# Trying to print character array in C

Tags: c

I am trying to print array of characters in C, but the array is not printing if any blank space occurs. This is my code:

```
int main() {
    char str[100];
    int len = 0;

    printf("Enter the string");
    scanf("%s", str);
    len = strlen(str);

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
       printf("%s", str[i]); 
    }    

    getch();
}
```

---

```
Input: Bangalore is in India
Output: Bangalore
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: %c is what you want, not %s

Comment: `%s` is the format specifier for a string. You are trying to print one character at a time (`str[i]`). So you should either, just once, do `printf("%s\n", str);` or, in your loop, do `printf("%c", str[i]);` and follow that with `printf("\n");` (newline string) or `putch('\n');` (newline char).

Comment: Also, scanf stops at the space.

Comment: This probably isn't that relevant but have you considered using [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) instead?

Comment: It is not working with %c ... It is printing the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html)
, the `%s` format skips leading white space, then scans non-white space characters and stops at the next white space in the input line.

That means that only `Bangalore` is read, so only `Bangalore` is printed.

If you want a whole line of input, you should probably use `fgets()`.

You should also be getting warnings from your compiler about your printing code.  You probably want to use this without a loop:

```
printf("%s\n", str);
```

or this within a loop:

```
printf("%c", str[i]);
```

though this would be faster:

```
putchar(str[i]);
```

and you would need to worry about adding a newline at the end (`putchar('\n');` after the loop).

Comment: Even this would print only bangalore .... I want the whole string to be printed...

Comment: To read in the whole string rather than just `Bangalore`, you have to read the whole string.  Like I said, you need to use `fgets()` unless you want to use `" %99[^\n]"` instead of `"%s"` in your scanf call.  It is fiendishly difficult to use `scanf()` and its relatives correctly.  They're seductively simple on the surface, but horribly complex once you start getting down to real business with them.

Answer (score 1):

Reading input from terminal would stop if it encountered a space or a new line. You could do 2 things to get what you need

1. Use fgets, ex : `fgets(str, 100, stdin)`
2. Tell scanf to read input while it's not a newline like this `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", str);`

and the second thing,if you are printing out character arrays, you must use %c

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual pages

you need %c not %s